# If we know a bound for the third derivative and 3 roots for a function, how can we derive its possible maximum value?

Tags: calculus, mean-value-theorem

The following problem was presented by a guest who gave a talk at our problem-solving seminar:

> Suppose $f$ is at least $3$ times differentible on $(-1,1)$, and $f,f^{'}, f^{''}, f^{'''}$ are continuous on $[-1,1]$.
> Moreover $|f^{'''}(x)| \leq 1$ on $[-1,1]$ and $f(-1) = f(0) = f(1) = 0$. What is the maximum value $f$ can take on $[-1,1]?$

I have been thinking about this, and my guess is that I will need to use the mean value theorem(to get bounds for $f^{'},f^{''}$) and the Landau inequality, but I don't have a good way maximize the ratio $|\frac {f^{'2}} {f^{''}}|$ given the roots condition.

Comment: Try assuming $f$ is a degree 3 polynomial, and you're going to get a first guess at the right answer, and a healthy likelihood of it actually being the correct one (seeing as it is the most greedy utilisation of the $f'''$ bound).

Comment: @Arthur I did guess $f(x) = 1/6 \cdot (x-1)x(x+1)$, but I grew less confident because I don't know how to give a proof.

Comment: The standard approach, assuming that's the true answer, would be: Assume there is a function that does better than $\frac{\sqrt3}{27}$. Use the mean value theorem to show that it must have $|f'''|>1$. Or, if it's not the true answer, maybe trying to write out this proof gives you an idea for how a function could do better.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry but I don't understand how I can use the MVT to get to $|f^{'''}|$. I think there's a step here I'm missing. For example, suppose $x_0$ is a maximum of $f$ such that $f(x_0) > \frac {\sqrt{3}} {27}$, then we know one of $\{ -1,0,1\}$ must be at most $\frac {1} {2}$ from $x_0$, so we can get a $x_1$ such that $|f^{'}(x_1)| \geq \frac {2 \sqrt{3}} {27}$, what to do afterwards? Also for the guessed example the maximum of $f^{'}$ is already $\frac{1}{3}$, so I doubt this will lead me anywhere.